# Removing trailing zeros from BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to remove trailing zeros from `BigDecimal` along with `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`. For instance,

```
Value        Output

15.3456  <=> 15.35
15.999   <=> 16            //No trailing zeros.
15.99    <=> 15.99
15.0051  <=> 15.01
15.0001  <=> 15           //No trailing zeros.
15.000000<=> 15           //No trailing zeros.
15.00    <=> 15           //No trailing zeros.
```

[`stripTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--) works but it returns scientific notations in situations like,

```
new BigDecimal("600.0").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
```

In this case, it returns `6E+2`. I need this in a custom converter in JSF where it might be ugly for end users. So, what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--)

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("600.0").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(d.toPlainString()); // Printed 600 for me
```

I'm not into JSF (yet), but converter might look like this:

```
@FacesConverter("bigDecimalPlainDisplay")
public class BigDecimalDisplayConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        throw new BigDecimal(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        BigDecimal  bd = (BigDecimal)value;
        return bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
    }
}
```

and then in xhtml:

```
<h:inputText id="bigDecimalView" value="#{bigDecimalObject}" 
    size="20" required="true" label="Value">
    <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalPlainDisplay" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 50):

Note that [`stripTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--) doesn't do very well either.

On this:

```
val = new BigDecimal("0.0000").stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(val + ": plain=" + val.toPlainString());

val = new BigDecimal("40.0000").stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(val + ": plain=" + val.toPlainString());

val = new BigDecimal("40.50000").stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(val + ": plain=" + val.toPlainString());
```

Output (Java 7):

```
0.0000: plain=0.0000
4E+1: plain=40
40.5: plain=40.5
```

Output (Java 8):

```
0: plain=0
4E+1: plain=40
40.5: plain=40.5
```

The `0.0000` issue in Java 7 is fixed in Java 8 by the following [java fix](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/2ee772cda1d6).

Comment: This worked for me. The 0.0000 amounts are still weird, but it cleans up the rest of the possible values from having ~dp worth of 0's trailing them when the precision requested is less than available.

Comment: Not what I found... Your first example about stripping zeros from "0.0000" yields "0" both with "toString()" and with "toPlainString()". Are we doing something different? http://ideone.com/fjS4qE

Comment: Java 8 fixes a bug, so the first example is "0" (Java 7 behavior is "0.0000").

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do this at your BigDecimal object and not convert it into a String with a formatter you can do it on Java 8 with 2 steps:

1. stripTrailingZeros()
2. if scale < 0 setScale to 0 if don't like esponential/scientific notation

You can try this snippet to better understand the behaviour

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
if (bigDecimal.scale()<0)
    bigDecimal= bigDecimal.setScale(0);
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//50
bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50.20"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
if (bigDecimal.scale()<0)
    bigDecimal= bigDecimal.setScale(0);
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//50.2
bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//5E+1
bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50.20"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//50.2
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. BigDecimal sets the scale to negative values when using scientific notation.

Answer (score 6):

You can also accomplish this with [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), like so:

```
final BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("600.0").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
String f = String.format("%.0f", b);
System.out.println(f); //600
```

Comment: A number like `999.99` returns `1000` but it returns the same `999.99` with `.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()` as it should do. So, it doesn't appear to be the exact representation like `BigDecimal`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You should make some calculation on the BigDecimal, and then round it half up e.g.

```
    BigDecimal toPay = new BigDecimal(1453.00005);
    toPay = toPay.multiply(new BigDecimal(1)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).
For example:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("15.3456").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
String valueString = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(value);
System.out.println(valueString); //15.35
```

Please try yourself.