# BigDecimal with smart precision (scale)

Tags: java, rounding, scaling, bigdecimal, autoscaling

How to set generic scaling according to decimal roundness as a number

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(25)

BigDecimal result = num.divide(new BigDecimal(13), 7, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
// 1.9230769
```

but

```
BigDecimal result = num.divide(new BigDecimal(10), 7, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN) 
// 2.5000000 that should  be 2.5
```

Probably analyzing remainder?

Is there something in the API for such case?

Comment: `BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()` perhaps? e.g. `BigDecimal result = num.divide(new BigDecimal(13), 7, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).stripTrailingZeros();` See:
 [BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()) and [Removing trailing zeros from BigDecimal in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770886/removing-trailing-zeros-from-bigdecimal-in-java)

Comment: @d.j.brown it works 10x  you might answer to the question I will accept your answer

Comment: thanks but the question has already been answered in another question which I found so there is not value in re-answering, see the link above. This should be closed as duplicate or removed.

Comment: @d.j.brown I see

Comment: An appropriate answer would be to use the MathContext and set the precision since the op is specifically using division.  The linked question is specific about removing zeros though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look At https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("235.000");
System.out.println( bd.stripTrailingZeros() );
```