# BigDecimal remove zeros only after decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am sending Bigdecimal numbers in json object. I have an issue with zeros.
I tried stripTrailingzeros() functions but it is not working as expected

```
30.000 -> 3E+1 expectaion is 30
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Removing trailing zeros from BigDecimal in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770886/removing-trailing-zeros-from-bigdecimal-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the number in BigDecimal `val = 3E+1` (That is `val = new BigDecimal("30.000").stripTrailingZeros();`).

When you print this then out would be `3E+1`.

In order to make it plain string [toPlainString](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bigdecimal-toplainstring-method-in-java-with-examples/) will help you.

```
System.out.println(val.toPlainString());    // 30
```