# Avoid BigDecimal adding 0 java

Tags: java

I'm working on a web application. I have a Bigdecimal property in my JPA entity, this property is mapped with a column in my table. The type of this column is Numeric(1,8).

My problem is when I type a value like this: 1.4342, this value is persisted like this 1.43420000. The value that I want to show to the user is 1.4342.

Do you have any idea on how to prevent persisting 0 in my database, or how I can remove 0 when retrieving the value from database using java?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770886/removing-trailing-zeros-from-bigdecimal-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing trailing zeros from BigDecimal in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770886/removing-trailing-zeros-from-bigdecimal-in-java)

Comment: You need to distinguish between the number and its presentation to the user. You told your database that you want 8 decimal places so every number will be saved with 8 decimal places n your database. That however has nothing to to with how many decimal places you show the user when you display the number.

Comment: As per what @OHGODSPIDERS said it's the precision of the column in your database, if you don't need values saved to 8 dp then you can run `ALTER TABLE table_name
  MODIFY column_name NUMBER(1,4);` (for example). Otherwise you'd need to amend the value when querying the db and setting to a `BigDecimal` as per some of the previous comment suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has the same issue , i convert my variable to string then i start removing zero from the end of this string , this is how i do it :

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String amount = "1.08430000";

       for(int i = 0; i <= amount.length() ; i++){
         if (amount.endsWith("0")) {
             amount = amount.substring(0, amount.length() - 1) + "";

          }
       }

       System.out.println("RESULT without zero :" +amount);

     }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider just using this method? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()

Comment: Unfortunately your way is flawed.  Try `String amount = new BigDecimal("123200").toString();` and see what happens.  Just use **Matt's** suggestion.

Comment: @WJS they might need to use 'toPlainString'.